# date and time format change from American to British to include the name of the day.

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
exam_df['started date']
```

returns dates and times in the following format

```
0    2016-01-29 06:56:00
1    2016-01-29 09:14:00
2    2016-01-29 11:16:00
```

I want to change it so it returns

```
Friday 29/01/2016 06:56:00
```

Comment: Sharing your to-do list with us won't get it done. Get cracking on it. :)

Comment: Or put another way, what have you tried? What isn't working? What can we help you with beyond "do this for me"?

Comment: You need to put together a better [mcve] in order for the community to give this question the proper attention. As is, it is too broad. Furthermore, is this a `pandas` related question? If so, did you check to see what is supported in `pandas` for date format manipulations?

Comment: Refer this post. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: @john Make sure you edit your question and properly format the code in your question. Do not put code in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `to_datetime()` to first convert the entries into datetime objects, and then apply `strftime()` to each entry to convert it back to your desired output format as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["2016-01-29 06:56:00", "2016-01-29 09:14:00", "2016-01-29 11:16:00"],  columns=['started date'])
dt = pd.to_datetime(df['started date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print dt.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%A %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Giving you:

```
0    Friday 29/01/2016 06:56:00
1    Friday 29/01/2016 09:14:00
2    Friday 29/01/2016 11:16:00
```

This makes use of the [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) formatting rules as follows:

`%Y` - Year with century as a decimal number.
`%m` - Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%d` - Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%H` - Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%M` - Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%S` - Second as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%A` - Weekday as locale’s full name.

Comment: @john, hopefully this does what you need? Don't forget, when you are happy with any solution to a question to click on the grey tick under the up/down votes to accept it as the solution... you would also earn a Scholar badge.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a useful function in javaScript

```
function usToBr (n:String) {
    var aDt=n.split(' ')
    aDt[0]=aDt[0].split('-')
    var _date:Date = new Date((aDt[0][0]), (aDt[0][1])-1, (aDt[0][2]));
    var dayOfWeek_array:Array = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

    var day_str:String = dayOfWeek_array[_date.getDay()];
    return day_str+' '+aDt[0][2]+'/'+aDt[0][1]+'/'+aDt[0][0]+' '+aDt[1];
}
```

Comment: And why is that useful on a question tagged with Python and not JS?

Comment: Why did you provide a javascript solution? How is this helpful at all?

Comment: Oh , I didn't see Python